# tikz, pgfplots, different colors for negative/postive z-values in addplot3

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, 3d

I want to color all points with negative z-values in the plane below red and all with positive z-values cyan!80. I searched for an hour now, but have no clue how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\pu{3}
\def\po{20}
\def\ku{2}
\def\ko{10}
\def\K{2000000}
\def\MP{500000}
\def\eo{\po-\ku}
\def\eu{\pu-\ko}
\def\layerwidth{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={20}{20},
    grid=major,
    z buffer=sort,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=\eu,ymax=\eo,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    ytick={},
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    zlabel={z},
    colormap={summap}{
        color=(red); color=(white); color=(cyan!80)
    },
    scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
    ]
        \addplot3
            [surf,
             domain=0:1,y domain=\eu:\eo]
            {(x*\MP)*y-\K};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `point meta min=-1, point meta max=1` (or some other small range that's symmetric about 0`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\pu{3}
\def\po{20}
\def\ku{2}
\def\ko{10}
\def\K{2000000}
\def\MP{500000}
\def\eo{\po-\ku}
\def\eu{\pu-\ko}
\def\layerwidth{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={20}{20},
    grid=major,
    z buffer=sort,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=\eu,ymax=\eo,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    ytick={},
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    zlabel={z},
    colormap={summap}{
        color=(red); color=(white); color=(cyan!80)
    }
    ]
        \addplot3
            [surf,
             domain=0:1,y domain=\eu:\eo, point meta min=-1, point meta max=1]
            {(x*\MP)*y-\K};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```